# Why do negative bruijn indexes show on the readback of interaction nets to λ-terms?

Tags: algorithm, lambda-calculus, interaction-nets

In order to evaluate terms of the untyped lambda calculus using Lamping's Abstract Algorithm, you have to first convert them to interaction nets, then normalize those nets, and then use a readback procedure to get a λ-term back. This always results in usual λ-terms. But if you stop the execution of the algorithm midway through the computation and apply the readback algorithm on that, it seems like you get negative bruijn indexes. Below I made a video to illustrate this point:

[The video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhNtgbFTXFE&feature=youtu.be) (I don't know how to inline it here.)

Why do negative indexes show up? Are terms with negative indexes meaningful in any sense?